# Приватный член в обьявлении

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть не статический метод:

```
 int make_dir(const std::string& name, Dir* cur_dir = _cur)
 {///}
```

_cur - приватный член. Этот код нельзя компилируется, но поясняет мою задумку: если функция вызвана с одним аргументом, то cur_dir инициализируется _cur объекта, с которого был вызван. Можно сделать так

```
 int make_dir(const std::string& name, Dir* cur_dir = nullptr)
 {
      if(cur_dir == nullptr)
          cur_dir = _cur;
  ///
 }
```

Но выглядит это не особо правильно, да и методов таких будет многою. Есть ли способ корректно записать по умолчанию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, нестатические поля объекта не могут выступать в качестве аргументов по умолчанию. Поэтому остается либо ваш вариант с `if`, либо перегрузка данного метода в двух вариантах: с одним и с двумя параметрами

```
int make_dir(const std::string& name, Dir* cur_dir) { ... }
int make_dir(const std::string& name) { return make_dir(name, _cur); }
```